# Simplest way to add stills to MP3 audio soundtrack

Tags: audio, video, video-editing, slideshow

I have some audio and want to add visuals to it and upload to YouTube.

Nothing fancy, just like slides, `image_A` from `00:00:00` to `00:00:05` then `image_B` from `00:00:50` to `00:00:30` and so on.

I have recent Mac and Windows machines to do this on.  I'd like to do it on free or demo software if I can.

Please give a bit of a hint how to get started if you can. I took a look a iMovie, but ... where to start, if you haven't actually got video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* iPhoto will export a slide show with audio as a movie.  If you want more control then an auto advance slide show then use iMovie.

In iMovie  create a new project, add your audio track and then add still images along the time line.

Comment: Thank you. I've got a little way into the process with iMovie already.

Answer (score 2):

Both Mac and Windows ship with video editing software built in.  I'm on a PC right now so I can't comment on Apple's version, but Movie Maker on your Windows machine is pretty easy to use and is more than capable to do what you're asking.

For simple slideshows you can also use PowerPoint.